# Execute custom command using subprocess that is in PATH variable

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, command

I want to execute another program that I compiled earlier from python using the `subprocess.call(command)` function.

However, python states that it cannot find the command. I suspect that subprocess is not able to find my custom command since it does not know the `PATH` variable of my Ubuntu system. Is it possible to somehow execute the following code, where command is part of my `PATH`?

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run("command -args")
```

Running this code leads to the error `command not found`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either provide the explicit path to your command:

```
subprocess.run('/full/path/to/command.sh')
```

or else modify your `PATH` variable in your Python code:

```
import os
os.environ['PATH'] += ':'+'/full/path/to/'
subprocess.run('command.sh')
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the environment variables. But be careful when you pass arguments.

Try something like this:

```
import os
import subprocess

my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env["PATH"] = "/usr/test/path:" + my_env["PATH"]
subprocess.run(["command", "-args"], env=my_env)
```